# Несмотря на то(,) что

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, союзы

Когда в этом союзе *несмотря на то(,) что* ставится запятая, а когда нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от смысла:

*Вода в озере была достаточно чистая, несмотря на то что здесь гнездилось много птиц.*

*Вода в озере была достаточно чистая несмотря на то, что здесь гнездилось много птиц.*

Примеры Розенталя:

> Раскольников молчал и не сопротивлялся, несмотря на то что чувствовал
>   в себе достаточно сил приподняться (Дост.); Несмотря на то, что ветер…
>   свободно носился над морем, тучи были неподвижны (М. Г.);

*Несмотря на то, что мысль пришла не ей, а младшенькой, старшая сестра с радостью присоединилась к идее, что лучше всего новые платья сшить.*

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=415

Answer (score 4):

Расчленение составных подчинительных союзов (постановка запятой внутри союза) может быть ФАКУЛЬТАТИВНЫМ или,  иначе говоря,  авторским.  В этом случае постановка запятой зависит: 1) от взаимного положения главного и придаточного предложения; 2) от  взаимной значимости главной или придаточной части. При расчленении составного союза меняется интонация СПП, что позволяет выделить главную или придаточную часть. Все сказанное можно отнести к союзу НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО, ЧТО.

Далее предлагаются наблюдения, позволяющие выразить авторскую позицию.

А) В НАЧАЛЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ сложные подчинительные союзы обычно не расчленяются (нейтральное значение): Несмотря на то что недалек был уже вечер, было душно.

При расчленении подчинительного союза подчёркивается ЗНАЧИМОСТЬ ПРИДАТОЧНОЙ ЧАСТИ, что связано с постановкой интонационного ударения на местоимение ТО, которое фактически указывает на придаточное предложение:   Несмотря на то, что Есенин неожиданно и стремительно ворвался в литературу, он был принят.

Б) Если придаточное предложение находится в конце СПП, то подчинительные союзы обычно расчленяются (нейтральное значение): Он отрицал свою вину  несмотря на то, что она была очевидна.

При отсутствии расчленения подчинительного союза подчёркивается ЗНАЧИМОСТЬ ГЛАВНОГО ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ, что связано с отсутствием интонационного ударения на местоимение ТО: Раскольников молчал и не сопротивлялся, несмотря на то что чувствовал в себе достаточно сил приподняться.

Answer (score 0):

Все, что сказали выше (или ниже, не знаю, где будет мой ответ), правда, но есть одно но. На сайте «Грамота.ру» говорится об этом союзе. Я про то, что в случае расчленения союза *несмотря на то что* запятая ставится и перед союзом тоже (по причине участия отглагольного предлога). То есть правильно: *Вода в озере была достаточно чистая, несмотря на то, что здесь гнездилось много птиц*; *Он отрицал свою вину, несмотря на то, что она была очевидна*.