# Подскажите, пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация

Пожалуйста, можете понятным языком рассказать, когда ставится запятая перед несмотря на то, что, а когда не ставится: несмотря на то что.

Comment: Можно посмотреть здесь: "Несмотря на то, что" https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/27063/Несмотря-на-то-что При формулировании вопроса пользуйтесь поиском по сайту.

Answer (score 0):

Открываем справочник и ищем параграф "Запятая при сложных подчинительных союзах".

"Понятным языком" частенько означает "приблизительно, на пальцах, как я вижу, как мне кажется" и т.п. (как в ссылке, приведенной в вышестоящем комментарии, человек (неспециалист!) "излагает свои соображения")

Вам это надо? Гораздо полезнее прочитать первоисточник – да, может быть, придется прочитать не один, а несколько раз, и вдумываясь.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138

Comment: В вышестоящем комментарии есть не только _изложение своих соображений_ неспециалистом, но и информация из первоисточника (правила о сложных союзах, по Лопатину), которую тоже полезно прочитать — и вдумываясь, и несколько раз.